# Встроенные средства мониторинга сетевого трафика?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть ли встроенные команды для просмотра текущего сетевого трафика в ubuntu?

Comment: `tcpdump` .....

Comment: http://blog.sedicomm.com/2018/11/16/20-instrumentov-komandnoj-stroki-dlya-monitoringa-proizvoditelnosti-linux/